# How to change redirected output?

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to change the text from redirected output?

For example, consider this code:

```
set status [catch {eval exec $executableName $options >@ stdout}  errorMessage] 
if { $status != 0 }  {
    return -code error $errorMessage
}
```

So if there is a "inside" `puts` let's suppose: `Hello world`, is it possible to print it out `Hello tcl`?

So I would like to do  something like this:

```
  catch {eval exec $executableName $options}  allPuts
  regsub -all "hello world" $errorMessage "hello tcl" allPuts
  puts $allPuts
```

But in this solution inside `puts` does not printed on the fly

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the output of `exec $executableName` and display it on `stdout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `exec $executable {*}$options >@ stdout` (a safer version of what you're using that is preferred for reasons that have *nothing to do with your question*), you are asking for the output of the subprocess to be sent straight to the outer process's standard output with no further processing. If you want to process things more first, you have to either direct the output through a filtering process before directing it to stdout or to bring it into the outer process for processing.

### Building a filtering pipeline

In this case, we're using the Unix program `sed` to do the filtering:

```
exec $executable {*}$options | sed {s/world/tcl/} >@ stdout
```

There are many options for doing this sort of thing; any of the many recipes for `sed` will (probably) work, so long as you remember that you are using Tcl syntax for `exec` and not shell syntax, so instead of `sed 's/world/tcl/'` you use `sed {s/world/tcl/}`.

If you prefer shell syntax, you do this:

```
set filter "sed 's/world/tcl/'"
exec $executable {*}$options | sh -c $filter >@ stdout
```

The script in `$filter` is pure Bourne shell.

### Processing inside Tcl

You can also do the transform inside Tcl. To do that on the fly, you need to work asynchronously on an opened pipeline.

```
# Define this procedure somewhere
proc transformLine {chan transform} {
    if {[gets $chan line] >= 0} {
        puts [string map $transform $line]
    } elseif {[eof $chan]} {
        catch {close $chan} ::doneWithPipe
    }
}

set pipe [open "|$executableName $options"]
fileevent $pipe readable [list transformLine $pipe {"world" "tcl"}]
vwait ::doneWithPipe
return -code error $::doneWithPipe
```

Note that you *have* to run the event loop (with `vwait`) for this to work.